# Can I use beforeinstallprompt to track how many users installed Native Apps?

Tags: android, google-chrome, analytics, manifest.json

I have a App Install Banner that shows on our mobile website. We are able to do this by using manifest.json. I need to be able to track how many users dismissed this banner and how many actually installed the banner. From what I have read I do something like

```
window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", function(e) {    
     e.userChoice.then(function(outcome) { 
      console.log(outcome);//Track this
     }, handleError); 
  });
```

I have read a few articles that has said, I cannot use this event in production or for analytics purposes ([here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent) and [here](https://github.com/w3c/manifest/issues/417)). Any reason idea why?

Thanks
K